# BookshelfJS return multiple pivot for BelongsToMany

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, bookshelf.js

I have two tables: `patches` and `devices`. The relationship here is `many-to-many`, and so I have a pivot table of `pivot_device_patch`.

The pivot table also has a column `status` that can be `available`, `failed`, `success`. There can be multiple of the same `patch` available for the `device` (i.e. the first one fails, so you create another request until it becomes successful).

I want to get all the instances of the pivot table, so I know how many has been pushed to the device. My query so far is:

```
new Device({guid : req.params.boxGuid})
    .fetch({withRelated: ['patches', {
            'patches' : function (qb) {
                qb.where('guid', '=', req.params.patchGuid);
            }
        }]
    }).then(function (device) {
        res.json(device);
    })
```

But this returns the very first entry in the pivot. How do I return ALL of them?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `qb.select('status');` before where statement.

I have very similar problem.

Comment: That wouldn't work. `qb` here refers to the table `patches` not the pivot table.